# How to transmission parameters like string data type in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to transmission parameters onto my function to excute

Here's my  stack.h file

```
#ifndef stackarray_h
#define stackarray_h
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 100;
typedef string Type;

class Stack{
private:
    Type item[MAX_SIZE];
    int top;
public:
    Stack();
    bool isEmpty()const;
    void push(Type value);
    void pop();
    Type getTop();
};

Stack::Stack(){
    top = -1;
}
bool Stack::isEmpty()const{
    if (top == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
void Stack::push(Type value){
    item[++top] = value;
}

void Stack::pop(){
    if (top != -1){
        top = top - 1;
    }
}

Type Stack::getTop(){
    return item[top];
}

#endif
```

Here's my source.cpp file. My problem that i can't transmission parameters  string  into stack to my push function.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include"stack.h"

void readFile(char* file,string &str);
void convertFromInfixToPostfix(string &str);
int evaluatingPostfix(string str);
int convert(int value);
string convertToString(int value);
int main(){
    string str;
    readFile("Text.txt",str);
    cout<<str<<endl;
    convertFromInfixToPostfix(str);
    cout << "Output: ";
    cout << str << endl;
    cout << "Result: ";
    cout << evaluatingPostfix(str) << endl;

    return 0;
}
void readFile(char* file,string &str){
    ifstream read(file);
    if (!read.is_open()){
        cout << "Error!.File wasn't opened." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        getline(read, str);
    }
    read.close();
}
void convertFromInfixToPostfix(string &str){
    Stack _stack;

    string output="";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < str.length()){
        if (str[i] == '(' || str[i] == '+' || str[i] == '-' 
        || str[i] == '*' || str[i] == '/' || str[i] == '%'){
            _stack.push(str[i]);
        }
        else {
            //excute character )
            if (str[i] == ')'){
                while (!_stack.isEmpty()){
                    char top = _stack.getTop();
                    output += top;
                    _stack.pop();
                }
            }else
            //excute character digit
            output = output + str[i];
        }
        // excute end of string
        if (_stack.getTop() == '('){
            _stack.pop();
        }
        i++;
    }
    str = output;
}
int evaluatingPostfix(string str){
    int result;
    Stack _stack;
    int op1, op2;
    int i = 0;
    int index;
    string temp;
    char next_ch;
    while (i < str.length()){
        next_ch = str[i];
        if (next_ch == '+' || next_ch == '-'
         || next_ch == '*' || next_ch == '/'
            ){
            //excute operator
            op1 = _stack.getTop();
            _stack.pop();
            // convert op1 to integer
            op1 = convert(op1);
            op2 = _stack.getTop();
            _stack.pop();
            // convert op2 to integer
            op2 = convert(op2);

            if (next_ch == '+'){
                index = op2 + op1;
                // convert index from integer to char
                 temp = convertToString(index);
                _stack.push(temp);
            }
            if (next_ch == '-'){
                index = op2 - op1;
                // convert index from integer to char
                temp = convertToString(index);
                _stack.push(temp);
            }
            if (next_ch == '*'){
                index = op2 * op1;
                // convert index from integer to char
                temp = convertToString(index);
                _stack.push(temp);
            }
            if (next_ch == '/'){
                index = op2 / op1;
                // convert index from integer to char
                temp = convertToString(index);
                _stack.push(temp);
            }
        }
        else {
            // excute integer
            _stack.push(next_ch);
        }
        i++;
    }
    // push the result onto the _stack
    result = _stack.getTop();
    // _stack is empty
    _stack.pop(); 
    return result;
}
int convert(int value){
    int result;
    result = value - 48;
    return result;
}
string convertToString(int value){
    string result ;
    int n = value;
    do{
        n = n % 10;
        result = result + (char)(n + 48);
    } while (n>0);
    return result;
}
```

There are error:

> Error 4   error C2664: 'void Stack::push(stackItemType)' : cannot
>   convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'stackItemType'

At line **_stack.push(temp);**
I'm sorry because my english isn't good.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: "Error was warned to IDE" - The error isn't some trade-secret. When you have problems with an error being received, *post that full, and *exact* error text in your question*. And since you're already posting an example, finish it so as to *reproduce* that error.

Comment: _"What's error?"_ Exactly. Please describe the error you get in your question.  Just saying _"I can't do that"_ is to vague to diagnose your problem.

Comment: It seems that you're trying to push to the Stack a string and it is expecting something of type StackItemType.

Comment: Yes @ivan .
I edited form "StackItemType" to "Type" at line typedef string "Type". 
But this is not my problem .

With method push(string value) . I try push item ( string item) onto stack but it's error

Comment: Ok. Try to cut down the code that is not relevant to the error, there is a lot of code in there. It would be easier to spot the error.